# How do you set the default route in MVC6 when using attributes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

In MVC5 you could set the default route using the following attribute on a controller?

[Route("{action=index}")]

What is the equivalent of this in MVC6?

**Update**

This is the code I had in MVC5

```
    [Route("{action=index}")]
    public class StaticPagesController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult About()
        {
           return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
           return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
```

I have not been able to work out how to do the equivalent in MVC6 but I've been able to get the same functionality working using the following:

```
    [Route("[action]")]
    public class StaticPagesController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult About()
        {
           return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
           return View();
        }

        [Route("/[action]")]
        [Route("/")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate your specific action method which you want to be the default action with `Route` attribute and pass `[controller]` as the route template to that. So anytime you get a request for `yoursite/yourcontroller`, the incoming request  will be redirected to this specific action method.

```
public class SettingsController : Controller
{      
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("[controller]")]
    public IActionResult OtherIndex()
    {
        return Content("This will be the response for mySite/Settings request");
    }
}
```

**Edit :** *As per the comment*

> I don't want to include the controller name in the URL.I want it to be
>   domain.com/About rather than domain.com/StaticPages/About

Using attribute routing, you can decorate your action method with the `Route` attribute and give `[action]` as the template name.

```
public class StaticPagesController : Controller
{      
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        // This action method will be executed for "yourSite/About" request
        return View();
    }
}
```

With the above approach, **you cannot have 2 action method's with the same name  in your app** ( *Ex : You cannot have an `About` action method in `HomeController` and `StaticPagesController`*)

Comment: [controller] on action?

Comment: @CoolBreeze yes. To make that action method  the default one for the controller.

Comment: This did not work.

I am not sure if it's because I have the following attribute on my controller:    

[Route("[action]")]
public class StaticPagesController : Controller

Comment: Yes. You don't need that controller level attribute. Try the code I have in the answer. It should work fine.

Comment: I do because I don't want to include the controller name in the URL. 

e.g. I want it to be http://domain.com/About rather than http://domain.com/StaticPages/About

Comment: Unfortunately this does not produce the desired behavior. Please see the update to my post for more information. I've got it working so it's no longer a big deal but still feels a little bit redundant...

Comment: It does. With the second update when you access yourSitename/About , It goes About of StatucPagesController. I am not sure why you think it is not the desired behavior ?

Comment: Because when someone visits yourSitename.com it should navigate to the  Index view.

Comment: It should work fine unless you have some custom route alteration.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. Oh well ended up using what was pasted in my question.

Comment: It should work. I created a minimal project and verified it, If you do not trust me, download it [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B9ABE38A81F442D6!3069&authkey=!AHyT8p2z_MaeVtg&ithint=file%2czip) and see yourself.

Comment: Your sample includes convention based routing in Startup.cs. I think that is why your example is working but not mine.